# what is the meaning of typedef base_type data_type?

Tags: c++

Often I see that cpp classes in the beginning of their declaration have this written

```
typedef base_type data_type
```

As far as I know, this has something to do with making your classes compatible with vectors. Can anyone guide me?

Googling this will also give you hundreds of links which use this statement.

Comment: they're merely using the type `data_type` instead of `base_type` so that `base_type` remains "hidden"

Comment: I guess you lost the `<…>` while copying.

Comment: typedef is used to define type aliases. It allows you to define data types with your own data type name. e.g: typedef Char myChar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typedef typename Base<T>::Foo Foo` is a common technique for template programming.

Since `Base<T>` depends on the template parameter `T`, the compiler can't know if for any particular type `T` the `Base` is specialized so that `Foo` is not a type (or exists at all).

So you have to tell the compiler that it should assume that `Foo` is a type.

It's a hassle, yes.

But then templates are incredibly useful, so it's well worth a bit of hassle. :)

---

Other than the above, a `typedef` just introduces an alternate name with only very subtle differences from the original.

For example, given `int x = 42;` the statement `x.~int();` is invalid, but `typedef int Int; x.~Int();` is OK.

Another such subtle difference is for definitions of constructors and destructor, where you must use the original class name.

---

In C++11 you can use `using` in much the same way as `typedef`, e.g. `using Int = int;`.

Comment: This(the first explanation) was exactly what I was looking for. Not sure why I got down voted. Thanks :)

Comment: @maddy1907 I didn't downvote, but I was considering it. The question gives next to no information or context. There's not a single word about templates, for example. Alf must have had a crystal ball to have guessed what you were after

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf  ,Angew thanks. I'll be more clearer with my questions henceforth.